# iphone UITableViewCell add image

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview

I have a subclass of TableViewController,and initWithStyle method like:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {        
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 280)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I want to add background image to my every TableViewCell,and image is displayed ,but it just displayed part of the image(my image size is 320 × 48),my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg_light.png"];    
    return cell;
}
```

and the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg_light.png"]];
```

or you can use

```
UIView *cellBackView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
cellBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg_light.png"]];
cell.backgroundView = cellBackView;
```

Comment: table cell is divided in two part first is imageview and second text label.

Comment: imageview is set in left side of cell. you can refere http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html